How to update WordPress & PHP when they are installed by Docker
Docker image
I have installed WordPress with Docker guided by this tutorial:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-wordpress-with-docker-compose
The tutorial is using this docker-compose.yml file that is using wordpress:5.1.1-fpm-alpine image:
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:8.0
    container_name: db
...

  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:5.1.1-fpm-alpine # <-- Note the WordPress version here
    container_name: wordpress
...

Outdated WordPress version
Now, I have to install some plugins, but they are requiring some newer versions of the WordPress. Like the WP phpMyAdmin plugin:

This plugin doesn’t work with your version of WordPress. Please update WordPress.


The WordPress dashboard is displaying update notifications too:

WordPress 6.7.1 is available! Please update now.


Try to update
But when I click on the Please update now. link, I receive this error:

You cannot update because WordPress 6.7.1 requires PHP version 7.2.24 or higher. You are running version 7.2.18.


Question
How can I reliably update the WordPress along with PHP? I don't want to mess up the whole Docker setup.

I guess I have to modify the Docker image to something like image: wordpress:6.7.1-fpm-alpine but I'm not sure if it would break the whole setup :(

What are the points I have to keep in mind? I'm trying not to miss anything.

While updating the WordPress Docker image, should I update the database image: mysql:8.0 too?

You could just backup your current setup, then modify your Docker image and see what happens. If stuff breaks then you have a backup to restore everything to how it was before.

@cabrerahector What kind of backup you have in mind? By operating system you mean? Or by Docker itself somehow?

Take a backup of your database and site files, and the docker-compose.yml file as well if you want to, then update your image.

@cabrerahector You mean the contents of the volumes that are stored in this directory on the host filesystem: /var/lib/docker/volumes/?

First and foremost, wordpress:5.1.1-fpm-alpine doesn't seem to be an official Wordpress image. These are always kind of hard to maintain, easy to set up, but a whole lot of headache to maintain. Anyway, to do such an upgrade, you will have to upgrade wordpress and php inside the container as well as their dependencies, goodluck with that! A better approach would be to create a backup of everthing (do a snapshot of the entire server if possible). Then run a new version of wordpress locally using a restored copy of the db, once everything works, you can use a newer image with that data.

I backed up the Docker named volumes. Then I updated the Docker image version, but the website threw 500 error. Then I restored the backup volumes. But website throws Error establishing a database connection error. Looks like updating WordPress & PHP by Docker might be a hassle even with backup/restore of Docker volumes.

The Error establishing a database connection is fixed now. I posed an answer to explain how.

The "Docker" way of updating a container is generally to download an updated image then stop and restart the container. They're meant to be easily recreated (which is why you have to set up where your database and other important files are stored, sometimes with Docker volumes, so that the storage remains intact when the container is recreated).
The official WordPress image seems to deviate from that a bit, it says at https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress the "default configuration for this image matches the official WordPress defaults in which automatic updates are enabled (so the initial install comes from the image, but after that it becomes self-managing within the /var/www/html/ data volume)," so I believe their intention is for you to manage updates entirely within the WordPress automatic update system.
However, doing that with a version-specific tag won't work well, you probably would want a general Docker tag like latest because if you were to recreate the container after it automatically updates, it wouldn't be good to jump backwards in versions to the version you have pinned (5.1.1 in your question). Who knows what backwards-incompatible changes could be introduced in the future, or what security flaws could be found. So I think I'd suggest pulling the wordpress:latest (which is not the FPM version) or if you really want the FPM then it looks like you'll have to stick to dictating the major version with wordpress:6-fpm.

You cannot update because WordPress 6.7.1 requires PHP version 7.2.24 or higher. You are running version 7.2.18.

This has to do with the outdated image you're running, which I imagine can be fixed by pulling in a newer Docker image that has a more updated PHP.
Note that while you are forcing version 5.1.1, that is SIX YEARS OLD at this point and you really should not be running such an old version of WordPress. You should also consult the WordPress documentation for the major upgrade from version 5 to 6 in case there's any additional action required on your part.

Update by Docker image version
It didn't work
I updated the Docker images like this:

But, the website threw the 500 error:

Bad restore
I had taken backups of Docker named volumes by this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/79247304/3405291
So, I did restore the Docker named volumes. However, the website threw this error:

Error establishing a database connection


Fix restore
The database connection error got fixed. To do so, I deleted everything inside the database volume by rm -rf * command:
/var/lib/docker/volumes/wordpress_dbdata/_data/

Then I restored the Docker volume of the database.
This screenshot shows the contents of the database volume before deleting/restoring and after:

As can be seen, before deleting everything, there were some extra files. Probably those files were messing around with the database connection.
Implication
The update by modifying the version of Docker images didn't work. But backup/restore helped us.

As suggested, another upgrade approach might be this:

So you'll have to go into the container itself and update it manually - like if it was an actual computer running Alpine Linux and you needed to upgrade it. You can look around for instructions on how to do that.

It's not tested yet. I will give it a try later.
